# Reading multiple images as tensors using tf.map_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am reading in various images (data and labels) in using Tensorflow's Dataset API. Since the Dataset queues are on the CPU, copying data around is expensive. However, I can't seem to find a way to avoid that.

**Question**: Can I efficiently load various kinds of images in a unified order (e.g. h,w,c)?

Let's say I want to read in a single single-channel image, I can do that as follows:

```
image = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(file_name), channels=1)  # h,w,c
```

Or for multi-channel RGB:

```
image = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(file_name), channels=3)  # h,w,c
```

This gives me a height-width-channel ordering, which is convenient for data-augmentation and pre-processing functions such as `tf.image.per_image_standardization`.

However, if I load multiple images and want to stack them together (e.g. a CNN with multiple RGB inputs or a multi-label semantic segmentation problem), I always seem to have to copy the data. Here is one way using a copy in `tf.stack`:

```
images = []
for image_id in range(0, images):
    file = file_names[image_id]
    images.append(tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(file), channels=1)[:, :, 0])
images = tf.stack(images, axis=2)  # Packs as h,w,c
```

Another way is using `tf.map_fn`, which looks like it was meant for this purpose. However, it 'stacks' in the wrong dimension, so I still need an expensive transpose:

```
map = tf.map_fn(lambda f: tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(f), channels=1)[:, :, 0],
                file_names, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.uint8)
images = tf.transpose(map, [1, 2, 0])  # from c,h,w to h,w,c
```

Is it possible to avoid the `tf.stack` or `tf.transpose`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is pretty hard to remove copies because tensors are generally immutable. Whenever an op wants to output something it will allocate new memory and write to it.

One could imagine changing `map_fn` implementation to stack tensors along a different dimension. Unfortunately, it is built using TensorArray, which does not support this.

One thing to note is that CHW is usually better for GPUs as they prefer inner dimensions to be larger. Most TF operations support this layout.

If you feel adventurous, you can try running this part through [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/). Because XLA gets a global view of your graph, it can potentially optimize some of these operations away. It is under heavy development and might or might not benefit your use case.

You can also look at official tensorflow models working with images (e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet) for best practices.

Comment: In that case this is a big flaw in TensorFlow's Dataset API design, because this simple transpose stresses my CPU's DRAM such that I can't maximize usage of the GPU. What you said about NCHW/NHWC is irrelevant at this point, because I'm still within the Dataset API where the pre-processing is, which has certain requirements unfortunately. If I could move the transpose out of the Dataset API then I could run it on the GPU and things are solved, but I can't with the current design.

Comment: It is not a design flaw, it is engineering resource allocation issue. Folks are working on allowing parts of Dataset API processing to run on GPU. In this case, however, if you have more CPU pre-processing to do after the transpose, running the transpose on GPU will not help since copying the data to GPU, doing transpose, and copying back is almost certainly more expensive than transpose on CPU.